# Check if element has any children?

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I am trying to remove an element from the DOM if it does not contain any elements.

Here is what I tried:

```
var numChildren = 0;
$("#messages").children().each(function () {
    numChildren += 1;
});
if (numChildren <= 0) {
    $("#messages").slideUp("normal", function () { $(this).remove(); });
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
var messages = $('#messages');
if (messages.children().length < 1) {
    messages.slideUp('normal', function () { $(this).remove(); });
}
```

Don't forget though that this will remove the `messages` div from the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

You could also simply use `$("#messages:empty").remove();`, though you'd need to trim whitespace to make the element truly empty.