# jQuery if element does not contain element then create and append one?

Tags: jquery

I have a `li` element that I am selecting like this:

```
var parent_li = $(this).parent();
```

This element may or may not contain an `ul` element. I would like to add a child to the `ul` but if there is no `ul` element I would like to create and add it first.

I tried:

```
if( !parent_li.children('ul') )
{
   //if the parent list doe not contain
   //an UL element, then add one
   parent_li.append($('<ul></ul>'));
}
```

However, I found out that parent_li.children('ul') always returns an object even if it does not have any child `ul` elements.

So what do I need to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery check if element has any children?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321067/jquery-check-if-element-has-any-children)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (parent_li.children('ul').length == 0){
   parent_li.append($('<ul></ul>'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said, the `children` method won't ever return a falsey value. It returns a jQuery object with zero or more matched elements. You have to check the `length` instead:

```
if( !parent_li.children('ul').length )
{
   //if the parent list doe not contain
   //an UL element, then add one
   parent_li.append($('<ul></ul>'));
}
```